# Why changes to regkey ProxySettingsPerUser does not affect IneternetSetOption(), if WinInet library iss already loaded in the process

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, winapi, proxy, wininet

I  have a requirement, that I want to configure proxy setting for entire machine programmatically. In my code I am first creating below reg key

HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxySettingsPerUser = 0

After successful creation of reg key, from the same process I am calling InternetSetOption to set proxy settings machine wide. Even if call is successful, machine wide proxy setting is not set. But if above key is already created before my process starts I am able to set machine wide proxy setting from the same code.

My guess is this is that since WinInet is already loaded in the process and after that I created reg key from the same process, WinInet did not honored above reg key changes.

I am able to solve this by loading WinInet dynamically(Call LoadLibrary for WinInet after reg key creation).

My question - Is there any better option available for this ?